# Are GameSalad and other visual programming "languages" on topic here?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, off-topic, scope

Are tools like [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu), [Alice](http://www.alice.org), and [GameSalad](http://gamesalad.com) considered on topic? I see in a lot of questions users saying in the comments that the question is too simple for the site, since it is for "experts", and these tools seem to be for beginners to programming.

Comment: It's worth noting there are tags for [tag:mit-scratch] and [tag:alice], though with 16 and 13 questions respectively they're not heavily traveled (which means you might not get the answers you're looking for).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, visual programming languages are on-topic on Stack Overflow.  Individual questions may be too simple if their answers can be found in any introductory tutorial, but we don't classify whole programming languages as off-topic just because they're aimed at beginner programmers.  If you have a question that you can't find the answer to in a tutorial or book for your language, go ahead and ask it.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering because I've seen a few questions now and then and I've been curious about if they're within the scope of the site.

Comment: @qegal No problem.  If we started excluding languages because they're aimed at beginners, some people would argue that we should get rid of all VB, PHP, and <insert your least-favorite language here> questions as well.  ;)

Comment: Note that scratch may not be off topic, but if you're 13 or under, technically you'll need to get someone to ask your question for you... ;)